webpack asset/resource Invalid configuration
Getting this Error in webpack configuration file, can anyone guide me.
Error: ___
Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.

configuration.module.rules[4].type should be one of these:
"javascript/auto" | "javascript/dynamic" | "javascript/esm" | "json" | "webassembly/experimental"
-> Module type to use for the module

const webpack = require("webpack");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const webpackBundleAnalyzer = require("webpack-bundle-analyzer");

process.env.NODE_ENV = "development";
module.exports = {
  mode: "development",
  target: "web",
  devtool: "source-map",
  entry: "./src/index",
  output: {
    // path: "/Volumes/ist_business_applications/ist_docstor/ui", // MAC mapped drive
    path:"\\\\dv-suite-cf-01\\f$\\wwwroot\\ist_business_applications\\ist_suite\\ist\\hr\\executivepresenceadmin",
    publicPath: "/ist/hr/executivepresenceadmin/",
    filename: "js/[name].[contenthash:8].js",
    // clean: {
    //   keep(asset) {
    //     return (
    //       (asset.includes(".cfc") || asset.includes(".cfm")) &&
    //       !asset.includes("index.cfm")
    //     );
    //   },
    // },
  },
  stats: "minimal",
  plugins: [
    // define global constants for use in build and run
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      // This global makes sure React is built in correct mode.
      "process.env.NODE_ENV": JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV),
      "process.env.BASE_CF_URL": JSON.stringify("/ist_docstor/"),
      "process.env.APP_BASE_URL": JSON.stringify(
        "https://istists1.istmanagement.com/ist_auth/logon/"
      ),
      "process.env.CF_URL": JSON.stringify(
        "https://istists2.istmanagement.com/ist/hr/executivepresenceadmin/executive_presence_admin.cfc"
      ),
      "process.env.PDF_URL": JSON.stringify(
        "https://istists2.istmanagement.com/ist/hr/executivepresenceadmin/show_report.cfm"
      ),
    }),
    // Display bundle stats
    new webpackBundleAnalyzer.BundleAnalyzerPlugin({ analyzerMode: "static" }),
    // use template to create new CFM file with link to built JS file
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: "src/index.html",
      filename: "index.cfm",
      favicon: "src/assets/images/favicon.png",
    }),
  ],
  optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
      chunks: "all",
      minSize: 20000,
      maxSize: 240000,
      // minRemainingSize: 0,
      minChunks: 1,
      maxAsyncRequests: 30,
      maxInitialRequests: 30,
      enforceSizeThreshold: 50000,
      cacheGroups: {
        defaultVendors: {
          test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
          priority: -10,
          reuseExistingChunk: true,
        },
        default: {
          minChunks: 2,
          priority: -20,
          reuseExistingChunk: true,
        },
      },
    },
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/i,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "babel-loader",
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff|woff2)$/i,
        type: "asset/resource",
        generator: {
          filename: "js_styles/[name].[contenthash:8][ext]",
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif)$/i,
        type: "asset/resource",
        generator: {
          filename: "js_images/[name].[contenthash:8][ext]",
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.svg$/i,
        type: "asset/resource",
        generator: {
          filename: "js_images/[name].[contenthash:8][ext]",
        },
      },
      {
        test: /LICENSE$/i,
        loader: "file-loader",
        options: { name: "js/LICENSE.txt" },
      },
    ],
  },
};

Getting this Error in webpack configuration file, can anyone guide me.
